# How do I generate test data for my Python script?

Tags: python

A equation takes values in the following form :

```
   x = [0x02,0x00]  # which is later internally converted to in the called function to  0x300
   y = [0x01, 0xFF]
   z = [0x01, 0x0F]
```

How do I generate a series of test values for this function ?
    for instance I want to send a 100 odd values from a for loop

```
for i in range(0,300):
   # where a,b are derived for a range
   x = [a,b]
```

My question was a bit unclear so please let my clarify.
what I wanted to ask how I can do `x =[a,b]` generate different values for `a,b`

Answer (score 3):

use generators:

```
def gen_xyz( max_iteration ):
    for i in xrange( 0, max_iteration ):
       # code which will generate next ( x, y, z )
       yield ( x, y, z ) 

for x, y, z in gen_xyz( 1000 ):
  f( x, y, z )
```

Answer (score 1):

The hex() function?

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    a1, a2 = random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100)
    x = [hex(a1), hex(a2)]
    print x
```

..outputs something similar to..

```
['0x21', '0x4f']
['0x59', '0x5c']
['0x61', '0x40']
['0x57', '0x45']
['0x1a', '0x11']
['0x4c', '0x49']
['0x40', '0x1b']
['0x1f', '0x7']
['0x8', '0x2b']
['0x1e', '0x13']
```